# Unresolved external symbol error

Tags: com, visual-c++

I am getting the following error in my VC++ COM project. What is the problem in linking the lib files here?

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BVUOpen@8 referenced in function "unsigned int __stdcall AFunc(void *)" (?AFunc@@YGIPAX@Z)   CBillAcceptor.obj   BillAcceptorCOM

Answer (score 1):

Here are the explanation of the LNK2019 error : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx).

Look for a problem of definition about **BVUOPen** symbol ! The problem si inside the method **AFunc** Maybe, you haven't declare it correctly or haven't link the library or haven't export the symbol...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to link against some external library that contains the object code for the BVUOpen function. The name of that library is not obvious from your error message, but it should be possible to work out from the documentation you are coding from.